# how to read ejb timer configuration from properties file using ejb-jars.xml placeholders

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, ejb

Here is my EJB timer Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar version="3.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>NotificationScheduler</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.scheduler.NotificationScheduler</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <timer>
                <schedule>
                    <second>${scheduler.seconds:0}</second>
                    <minute>${scheduler.minutes:0}</minute>
                    <hour>${scheduler.hours:*/2}</hour>
                </schedule>
                <timeout-method>
                    <method-name>sendNotifications</method-name>
                </timeout-method>
            </timer>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

**How can I read properties like second, minute and hour form properties file and use them in my ejb-jar.xml as place holders, and if properties are not found it should use default values. I don't want to use programmatic timer configuration.**